# How can I include an arbitrary set of Protobuf-built files without knowing their names?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I'm planning on using the [rust-protobuf library](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf). I've written a bash script that builds everything (including my code) and builds the .proto files I have into .rs files. The way the documentation tells me to proceed is to specifically just do:

```
mod foo;
```

for each of the .rs files generated. I'm hoping that my users can just drop in new .proto files into a directory, run the build script, and my code will take care of including all of the Rust implementations of the compiled .proto files.

I know Rust doesn't really support reflection, so is there some way I can essentially "determine all the .rs generated files in a directory and use them in my code" (in a TLDR statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a [Cargo build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) which would scan your directory and generate a Rust file that looks like:

```
mod file1;
mod file2;
//etc
```

You can then include this file in your library with the [`include!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include!.html).

Comment: And then you might as well replace the bash script with the build script as well.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the route I will go down - didn't realize cargo supported build scripts.

@Shepmaster - I will also most-likely do that as well, since I'll be going down that path.