# How to determine messages in .rs files generated from rust-protobuf included by include! macro

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I previously asked [How can I include an arbitrary set of Protobuf-built files without knowing their names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504933/how-can-i-include-an-arbitrary-set-of-protobuf-built-files-without-knowing-their) - this is a follow up question based on the results of that.

I now have a file that I include that contains the different modules on their own line - i.e.:

```
mod foo;
mod bar;
```

These modules and their names can be totally random depending on what the user has put in the directory for the proto files.

I need to perform operations on those random modules. For instance, the first thing I would like to do is get all the messages that exist in those new modules and present them back as strings that I can push onto a vector.

So really a 2 part question:

1. Is there a way I can not know the names of the modules that I am now including in this file with include! and use the structures inside them (generically - now that I have them included).
2. After the above, how to get all the possible messages inside a protobuf generated .rs file/module. Each .rs file has a `FileDescriptorProto()` method, which looking on the Google protobuf documentation, looks similar to this: [Google Protobuf FileDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FileDescriptor)

Comment: I don't think you can. Essentially you are asking for reflection, which doesn't quite exist in the sense you need. As an example, consider the `#[test]` attribute, which basically does the same thing you want — it collects all the annotated functions and calls them. That is implemented as an addition to the compiler itself, not a technique available to most programmers. Instead, consider enhancing the file conversion tool to produce a well-known and required symbol that you can always trust to be there.

Comment: What if I made it a requirement that there was a top level proto file that did an "import <other_proto_file_here>.proto" (in the actual .proto file) for all of the other proto files. If I did that, could I just include that top level .rs file (that would be compiled) and then use the method that returns a FileDescriptorProto to get the other proto structures? Maybe I don't fully understand how the FileDescriptorProto() method works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this, based on @Shepmaster's suggestion in the comment on the original post:

Since Rust doesn't support reflection (at the time of this post), I had to expand my cargo build script to write code in the file that is being generated to have symbols that I would know would always be there.

I generated specific functions for each of the modules that I was including (since I had their module names at that point), and then generated "aggregate" functions that had generic names, that I could call back in my main code.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you include a single file that is generated by the `build.rs` script.  This script can scan the given directory and generate the proper file.

I do have an example I can link to, but it includes solutions to Project Euler solutions, so I'm not sure how people feel about that.

Here is the `build.rs` that I use:

```
// Generate the problem list based on available modules.

use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

use regex::Regex;

extern crate regex;

fn main() {
    let odir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_owned();
    let dst = Path::new(&odir);
    let gen_name = dst.join("plist.rs");
    let mut f = File::create(&gen_name).unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "// Auto-generated, do not edit.").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "pub use super::Problem;").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "").unwrap();

    let problems = get_problems();

    // Generate the inputs.
    for &p in problems.iter() {
        writeln!(&mut f, "#[path=\"{1}/src/pr{0:03}.rs\"] mod pr{0:03};", p, cwd).unwrap();
    }
    writeln!(&mut f, "").unwrap();

    // Make the problem set.
    writeln!(&mut f, "pub fn make() -> Vec<Box<Problem + 'static>> {{").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "    let mut probs = Vec::new();").unwrap();
    for &p in problems.iter() {
        writeln!(&mut f, "    add_problem!(probs, pr{:03}::Solution);", p).unwrap();
    }
    writeln!(&mut f, "    probs").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut f, "}}").unwrap();

    drop(f);
}

// Get all of the problems, based on standard filenames of "src/prxxx.rs" where xxx is the problem
// number.  Returns the result, sorted.
fn get_problems() -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut result = vec![];

    let re = Regex::new(r"^.*/pr(\d\d\d)\.rs$").unwrap();
    for entry in fs::read_dir(&Path::new("src")).unwrap() {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();
        let p = entry.path();
        let n = p.as_os_str().to_str();
        let name = match n {
            Some(n) => n,
            None => continue,
        };
        match re.captures(name) {
            None => continue,
            Some(cap) => {
                let num: u32 = cap.at(1).unwrap().parse().unwrap();
                result.push(num);
            },
        }
    }

    result.sort();
    result
}
```

Another source file under `src` then has the following:

```
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/plist.rs"));
```

Comment: Well, I mean, I'm already doing sort of that. My build script runs the protoc compiler against all the .proto files in a directory and creates a .rs file that has (mod foo; mod bar; etc... on seperate lines), which I then include in my main program.

The issue is that I don't know what modules will be included because the file names could be totally random, so I wouldn't know how to construct things, call implemented structure functions, etc.